# Add a Location to Windows 7 Search Index

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, indexing

Is there any way by which I can add a location to Windows 7 search index and make it indexed in .Net?

Answer (score 2):

Use the AddCatalog function in the Windows Indexing Service API:

```
void AddCatalog(string Name, string Location)
```

For VB Examples, see [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WinIndexingserviceBasic.aspx) as well.

Comment: I am not sure about the network locations. If you did it a try, please let me know the result. :)